# @Inherited annotation in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

Herbert Schildt mentions in his book on Java,

> `@Inherited` is a marker annotation that can be used only on another annotation declaration. Furthermore, it affects only annotations that will be used on class declarations. `@Inherited` causes the annotation for a superclass to be inherited by a subclass.
>
> Therefore, when a request for a specific annotation is made to the subclass, if that annotation is not present in the subclass, then its superclass is checked. If that annotation is present in the superclass, and if it is annotated with `@Inherited`, then that annotation will be returned.

I know pretty well that annotations are not inherited. Exceptions are annotations, which its declaration is annotated with `@Inherited`.

I have understood the rest of the annotations which includes java.lang.annotation: `@Retention`, `@Documented`, and `@Target`. and other three—`@Override`, `@Deprecated`, and `@SuppressWarnings`.

I am a bit confused when it comes to the `@Inherited` annotation. Could someone demonstrate it with a simple [foobar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) example?

Secondly, going through one of the questions regarding this on StackOverflow, I came across this,

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD) @Inherited
public @interface Baz { 
           String value(); }

public interface Foo{
    @Baz("baz") void doStuff();
}

public interface Bar{
    @Baz("phleem") void doStuff();
}

public class Flipp{
    @Baz("flopp") public void doStuff(){} 
}
```

What use does the `@Inherited` annotation have when put on the annotation `@interface Baz`?

Please don't explain me in context with annotations used Spring Framework, I am no in way familiar with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, as the quote you posted states,

> it affects only annotations that will be used on **class declarations**

So your example doesn't apply since you're annotating methods.

Here's one that does.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Bar.class.isAnnotationPresent(InheritedAnnotation.class));
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
//@Inherited
@interface InheritedAnnotation {
}

@InheritedAnnotation
class Foo {

}

class Bar extends Foo {
}
```

This will print `false` since the `CustomAnnotation` is not annotated with `@Inherited`. If you uncomment the use of `@Inherited`, it will print `true`.